# Understanding the induced EMF by a magnet through a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I just started self-studying physics again after some 20 years and I'm confused by this. So assume I have a wire loop and I move a magnet quickly through it. Then there will be an induced current $I$ in the loop. Now by Ohm's law, we get $V=IR$, so there's a potential difference somewhere. My question is where? Between what points would I find the potential difference? How should I conceptually think about this?

I can wrap my head around this in the case of a battery, where there are typically ions moving inside the battery against an electric field due to some phenomena (chemical reaction or even gravity) driving the current. However, the battery is at a fixed location in a circuit while the case of a wire loop is completely symmetric, so I don't see where the potential difference would be.

Is the problem here with my thinking that the electric field is not conservative, so integrating around the loop will not give me zero?

Answer (score 0):

The magnet and wire loop are just a conversion setup.  The force (the power in the system) is supplied by your arm moving the magnet (which eventually drives from the sun).  Once you accelerate the magnet up to speed and let go of it the power inheres in the magnet as momentum.  Mechanical force is converted to electrical energy by the loop and can be reconverted back to mechanical force at the other end of the wire with the exception that it will be lessened by heat loss due to resistance in the wire as the magnet decelerates again.